# Nodejs - Sequelize : postgresql encrypted at rest, iLike search

Tags: node.js, postgresql, encryption, sequelize.js

I'm looking to encrypt patient data (surname, first name, date of birth, address, etc.) at rest in my database.
However, I need to be able to perform a partial search in my database using only part of the surname and/or first name.

I'm using nodejs with sequelize and postgreSQL.

I know it's possible to use the pgcrypto extension in postgresql, and I'm able to encrypt the data this way, but my partial search doesn't work:

PatientModel.js :

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Datatypes) => {
    return sequelize.define('patient', {
        id: {
            type: Datatypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        firstName: {
            type: Datatypes.STRING,
            allowNull : true,
            set(value) {
                this.setDataValue('firstName', sequelize.fn('pgp_sym_encrypt', value, 'secret_key'));
            },
        },
        lastName: {
            type: Datatypes.STRING,
            allowNull : true,
            set(value) {
                this.setDataValue('lastName', sequelize.fn('pgp_sym_encrypt', value, 'secret_key'));
            },
        },
})}
```

PatientControllers.js :

```
exports.getPatient = (req, resp, next) => {
  PatientModel.findAll({
    attributes: [
      'id',
      [
        sequelize.fn(
          'PGP_SYM_DECRYPT',
          sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('firstName'), 'bytea'), 
          'secret_key'
        ), 
        "firstName"
      ],
      [
        sequelize.fn(
          'PGP_SYM_DECRYPT',
          sequelize.cast(sequelize.col('lastName'), 'bytea'), 
          'secret_key'
        ), 
        "lastName"
      ],
    ],
    where : {
      firstName : {
        [Op.iLike] : `${req.query.firstName}%` 
      },
      lastName : {
        [Op.iLike] : `${req.query.lastName}%` 
      },
    },
    order: ['firstName'],
    limit: 5
  })
  .then(patients => {
    console.log(patients) // nothing
    return reponse.status(200).json({ data : patients});
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
      return reponse.status(404).json({ data : error});
    }
  );
}
```

I think the problem is linked to the fact that the search is done with unencrypted data on data that hasn't yet been decrypted, but I can't do anything else. Of course, it's not possible to encrypt the query data in order to perform the search, as the data would never match...

I've also tried using the bcrypt dependency, but I'm having the same problem.

Thanks for your help !